# Smooth step function and an integral related to its Mellin transform

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, mellin-transform

Let $L>0$. Let $f(t)$ be a smooth step function that satisfies the following:
$f(t) = 1$ if $t \leq 1$ and $f(t) = 0$ if $t \geq 1 + (1/L)$. Let $Z>0$. I am interested in obtaining an upper bound for the Mellin transform (of a related function)
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x/Z) x^s \frac{1}{x} dx. 
$$

I am interested in learning what bound is available for this integral along with how I should choose such smooth step function or a good example of it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant a bound for $F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) t^{s-1}dt, \Re(s) > 0$. Then write $f(t) = 1_{t< 1} \ast \phi(t)= \int_0^\infty 1_{\tau < 1} \phi(t/\tau) \frac{d\tau}{\tau}=\int_0^1 \phi(t/\tau) \frac{d\tau}{\tau}$ where $\phi=f' \in C^\infty_c(0,\infty)$ so that by the (Mellin) convolution theorem $F(s) = \frac{1}{s}\Phi(s)$  where $\Phi(s) = \int_0^\infty \phi(t) t^{s-1}dt$ which is entire and Schwartz on every vertical line.

By Mellin/Fourier/Laplace inversion for $\sigma > 0$, $f(t) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma + i \infty} F(s) x^{-s} ds$ and for $\sigma < 0$ , $f(t)-1 = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma + i \infty} F(s) x^{-s} ds$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comments. I fixed the typos. I was really interested in the Mellin transform of $f(x/Z)$ so this part was not a typo.

Comment: @JohnnyT. What do you get with the change of variable $t = x/Z$

Comment: I see. Ok, thanks. Also for a fixed $L>0$, I wanted to be able to make sure that $f(t)$ satisfies $f(t) = 1$ for $t \leq 1$ and $f(t)=0$ for $t> 1 + 1/L$ (which I just realized is not what I wrote. I will fix that as well). Is this possible with this argument as well? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnnyT. What do you mean with "make sure" ? Do you see that the Mellin convolution is the normal convolution up to a change of variable $t = e^u$ ? What do you get when looking at $1_{u < 0} \ast \phi$ for $\phi$ supported on $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: By "make sure" I just meant that at the moment I am only interested in smooth step function that satisfies these properties, so I was curious to know if the resulting function in your answer satisfies these properties.

Comment: I think $(1_{u<0}* \phi) (x)$ is some function that is $0$ if $x>b$? I am not sure otherwise...

Comment: @JohnnyT. $(1_{x<0} \ast \phi) (x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{x-u < 0}\phi(u)du = \int_a^b 1_{x-u < 0} \phi(u) du$. Yes for $x > b$ it is $0$. And for $x < a$  ?

Comment: Oh, $\int \phi(z) \ dz$?

Comment: Ahhh, I think I am starting to get more of this. So by controlling the interval $[a,b]$ I can obtain the properties I want. I guess one of the other thing I was wondering was by putting this restriction (with $L$) does the bound on $F(s)$ perhaps depend on $L$ now?